# Can anyone explain this feature of the normal distribution?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, statistics

I was doing some questions involving the normal distribution when I saw that the percentage point of 0.95 is 1.6449, I know that 1.6449 is approximately $\pi^2 /6$, and I was wondering if anyone knew if there was a special reason behind this value of the normal distribution being equal to $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {n^{-2}} $$ or if it was purely a coincidence.

Thank you!

Comment: How exactly have you computed this $1.6449$? I assume it is pure coincidence as I think this is only approximately true *and* that $0.95$ is a pretty random number, but it would be better to first see what you mean by "percentage point".

Comment: I assume by "percentage point" you mean that value $x$ such that the probability that a standard normal variable is $≤x$ is $.95$ yes?  That comes out to $1.644853627$ while the sum yields $1.644934067$.

Comment: To go the other way, if you wanted to replace $.95$ by the value that would give you exactly $\frac {\pi^2}6$ you'd just need $0.950008296$.

Comment: So apparently it _is_ a coincidence.

Comment: @DavidK But a nice one! And with astonishing accuracy.

Comment: @Peter And a particularly interesting one because $0.95$ is a Z-score that frequently gets used. It would have been somewhat less interesting if the approximation were for $0.86$ instead of $0.95.$

Comment: @DavidK In fact! I never nocticed this approximation.

Comment: A Z-score of 0.95 is a convenience, and sometimes not a useful value. Although S. Ramanujan might have been able to find a nice neat  (and baffling) formula for the difference  from $\pi^2/6$ (if there is such  a formula).